# Configuring VSCode with CMake on Qt - ui_*.h files can't be found

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cmake, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to configure VSCode to run with a project written in C++ and Qt, using the Microsoft C/C++ Intellisense extension.

Some files include Qt ui headers, in the format:

```
#include "ui_filename.h"
```

However, these are underlined with red squiggles and the message:

```
#include errors detected. Consider updating your compile_commands.json or includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/path/to/my/workspace).
cannot open source file "ui_filename.h"
```

These files are in a directory `build.debug/`, which is a subdirectory of my root workspace directory.

I've tried to use the [CMake Tools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vector-of-bool.cmake-tools), by configuring it with only this:

```
"cmake.copyCompileCommands": "build/compile_commands.json"
```

`build` is the project's directory for all things to do with building.

The configuration for the C/C++ extension has these relevant lines:

```
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/**"
        ],
        ...
        "compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json"
```

However this still doesn't solve the problem. I've also tried installing the CMake Tools Helper extension, which ironically doesn't help.

I'm not really sure where to go from here. Everything else works fine, Qt definitions are all recognised and all normal headers a recognised. I've checked, and the ui header files definitely exist in my workspace. What can I do? Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're gonna have to manually add the files' paths into your project's include path. Take a look on the manual section [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/Getting%20started%20with%20IntelliSense%20configuration.md) for more info.

Comment: Stack Overflow answers should be self contained. Cite the relevant parts from the link in your answer please.